Can I use an element of a list to name a tibble within a loop in R?
The below is a very simplified example, but should demonstrate the issue I'm attempting to solve
df <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:5,3),
  m1 = rnorm(15),
  m2 = rnorm(15),
  m3 = rnorm(15),
  m4 = rnorm(15),
  m5 = rnorm(15)
)

I want to manipulate a tibble and end up with separate tibbles based on a variable name. I can run
list <- c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5")

for (i in 1:length(list)){
  name <- list[i]
  name <- df %>%
    select(id, all_of(name))
}

Which obviously overwrites name for each cycle of the loop. The result I am aiming for would be 5 tibbles each called the corresponding value from the list. Is it possible to get the value of name instead of "name" itself to be the left-hand side of the manipulation?
Edit
The actual manipulation of the tibble isn't selecting a single column which is why I haven't used sapply or similar. The final goal is to write an excel file with each tibble being a separate sheet. I've extended the code now to:
list <- c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5")

list2 <- NA

for (i in 1:length(list)){
  name <- list[i]
  sheet <- df %>%
    select(id, all_of(name))
  list2[i] <- list(name=sheet)
}

I thought naming the list elements might be easier but the 'name' within list seems to be ignored.

Try sapply(list, \(x) data.frame(id = df$id, df[x]), simplify = FALSE).

Thank you the actual manipulation of the tibble is more complicated and involving multiple columns, I'll add an edit to the question to give more details.

Are you trying to repeat the tibble length(df) times with each tibble assigned m1, m2, . . .?

setNames(list, list) |> lapply(\(name) select(df, id, all_of(name))) ? I'f it's still not warmer, then the confusing part is the use of name and all_of(name) in the context of /../ involving multiple columns /../ and I'm afraid that 2nd example doesn't help too much to make it clearer.  You also say that you want to /../end up with separate tibbles /../ , so tibbles as separate objects in (global) environment? Or is it still a named list of tibbles?

add list2 <- list2 |> set_names(name) after the loop

@ Ifeanyi one tibble for each element of list, so repeating length(list) times;
@ margusl I used all_of(name) as it gave an error when I just used name. I was aiming for separate tibbles in the global environment, but name within a list (as in the second example also works). I may see if I can write a function for the manipulation (it’s a table in long format converted to wide format after removing duplicates) and then use lapply;
@ mdag02 this does work. I was aiming within the loop to guarantee the correct label and output but as the order is fixed I guess this isn’t an issue.

To create separate tibbles in environment you can just use assign() in the loop,  for ( name in list ) { assign(name, select(df, id, all_of(name))) }

I think the simplest and cleanest way to do this would be to reshape, split into a list, and export to Excel.
Here, I used tidyr::pivot_table & purrr::map from the tidyverse metapackage, and rio::export, just because I like their defaults for this task.
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-id) %>%  # reshape long so the name of the source column is 
                                # in a new column called "name"
  split(f = .$name) %>%         # split by "name" into a list of tibbles
                                #  (much easier to work with downstream than a collection
                                #    of separate objects)
  purrr::map(~select(.x, -name)) %>%   # optional: remove the "name" column from each
  rio::export("~/file.xlsx")    # save to excel, with sheets using names of list elements
  

This will output an excel file with named tabs for each column.

